# Is mandatory to use void as outerscope in C programming..?

Tags: c

im trying to declare an array of three pointers to functions and invoke the appropriate function based on an index value passed in as an argument
im getting confused,this is the code i wrote

```
int brr,func,arr(int *a[3],float *b[5] ,char *c[6]) 
{
    brr();`func();`
    printf("%d\n",brr);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. What does "void as outerscope" mean? And how does it relate to the code you have shown? Can you please provide clearer and more description?

Comment: This code makes absolutely no sense. And why do you have backticks around `func();`?

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question and start with what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Your code either misunderstands the declaration of return values or tries to define variables and functions in a way which is to fancy for me (and possibly to compilers). Please make your code more straight forward and above all, compilable.

Comment: I'm trying to declare an array of three pointers to functions, after the declaration.Then i execute the appropriate function based on an index value i passed to a function .Let me rewrite in this way if you can my point clearer

void arr() 
{
    int brr[] = {5,8,2};
   // float  func[5];
    //char arr[6];
     
    printf("%d\n",*(brr + 1));
    
}

int main() 
{
    arr();
    return 0;
}

Comment: I've rewritten the code,but i think this is not my goal to achieve. I'm trying to declare an array of three pointers to functions and execute the appropriate function based on an index value passed to the function as an argument .